# What is a cheap, safe way to ship 7 dogs from Brazil to Belgium?

Tags: pets, shipping

I'm planning to move from Curitiba (Brazil) to Brussels (Belgium) by the end of the year, and have 7 dogs that I'd like to take with me. I'm looking for a cheap, reliable and safe way to transport them.

I got a quote from a vet specialised in pet shipping, but it's cost prohibitive, R$ 35.000 just the for the dogs. It's more than I have saved for the travel for my wife and I.

I tried looking for freighter shipping (I don't mind taking the ship with them, if it means I can care for them), but the ticket prices for a person are more expensive than air travel.

Someone suggested uShip.com, but if I understood correctly, they just connect a customer to a shipping company, and I have no way of knowing how reliable and safe it will be.

I'm totally lost.

Comment: From friends I know that have moved with pets the pet relocation (1 dog) has been as expensive or more expensive then their flights.  I would expect 7 dogs to be extremely expensive and R$35,000 or USD10,000 doesn't sound out of line to me.  Also does that quote include all the procedures the dogs need (microchips, rabies shots, medical check on arrival, any required quarantine, etc)

Comment: If you can't afford to ship your dogs, are you sure you can afford a large enough apartment to house them?

Comment: Have you asked the airlines directly? You might be able to take a couple at a time per person with you. If they are small beasts you might be able to get two to share a crate. You'll have to look into regulations regarding shots, quarantine etc.

Comment: This question should be on [Expatriates.SE].

Comment: @gtwebb The dogs are already microchipped. What's included in the package is rabies shots (very cheap), blood tests for paperwork, paperwork,   medical care before travel, van transport from Curitiba do São Paulo and an estimate for shipping as luggage (live cargo is extremely more expensive). No medical care at the destination.

Comment: @phoog I can afford the rent, a _rez-de-chausée_ (ground level apt. with backyard) is around €600/month.

Can an admin move the post to _Expatriates_.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I tried the airlines before contacting the pet-shipping vet, but they couldn't tell me the procedures, a lot of misinformation. One thing I found out is not to use the Brazilian air lines, they lose animals.

Comment: I haven't been able to find a reference beyond a comment on a pet travel website, but the person said that over 6 dogs requires a kennel license.

Comment: @mkennedy As far as I know the amount of dogs you can keep in a residential area in Belgium is 5, to have more you need to be listed as a kennel and live outside of a residential area. I tried looking for official information about this but could only find forum posts. I would suggest OP contacts officials in the residential area he wants to move to for more information before he ships out his pets.

Comment: I think checking the permitted number of dogs is important. If you are going to have to rehome one or more of them, it is probably better to leave them in a familiar climate and spare them the stress of long distance travel.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 Thanks for the heads up, I will look into it.

Comment: I brought 2 cats and costs about R$3k: ticket, vacines, microships, sorology, everything that it needs. So, taking in account the dogs are bigger than cats and need more things, it will probably costs you at least R$20k.